# Freezes when under load (possible past heat damage)

Tags: cpu, motherboard, freeze, overheating

I started getting freezes where the last frame on screen stays and the fans slowly speed up. Reset button has no effect and only holding the power button shuts the pc off. I tried another PSU and with and without discrete card. GPU is not actually getting detected at all in Windows.
Running CPU stress test freezes within seconds. Power at the wall exceeds 100W at the time of the crash so it seems power related. RAM test didn't detect any issues.

**Possible heat damage**

Several weeks ago I had a water cooler failure which caused the cpu to heat up presumably over 100C several times until I realised what the issue was.

What is the likely cause? Damaged CPU or Motherboard? Is there anything can be done to find out? Unfortunately I don't have compatible CPU to test the MOBO.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that heat could be an issue , unfortunately i do not know how to test the cpu. Are there any red/yellow LED's lit up on the MOBO when this happened? Usually a CPU or DRAM LED will light up red.

"Power at the wall exceeds 100w" :
What is your mains voltage ? If its 110 then its drawing about an amp(normal) and if its 220 its drawing about half an amp(also normal).
*Normal depends on make , model and size of PSU of course.

Its quite possible that its cpu problem, but they generally can withstand up to 150°C.

Do you hear any clicking from the psu ? (clicking indicates that the current limiter is kicking in and that means there is aa issue somewhere)

Comment: My PSU was 760W Corsair and I also tried 400W BeQuet. There's no clicking or other abnormal sounds. 100W just seems to be the point when it fails, may be directly related or just coincidental. I dont believe there are any indicator LED's on the mobo but will double check later. CPU is already 4 years old with very minor overclock but still I would guess it's the mobo, Asrock are not known for quality...

Comment: Yeah mobo could be damaged, If posible check for warping. Other than that ,and what i mentioned earlier, i havent the slightest clue to what causes it. Also, if youre going to buy a new mobo ,have this one checked out by a pc shop that can to make sure that it is indeed the mobo that went.

Comment: It woun't be worth having it checked, if it's not the MOBO then I will know after I run the stress test. Since it's a few years old now I will probably have to get new CPU and Motherboard, not worth getting a mobo with 1155 socket and no DDR4 support I think...